# Delphi - 7 Segment Display

Tags: delphi

I am trying to solve a problem. I want to display multiple I/O functions (write_byte()) on a 7 segment display. I am using a PCF8574 iic. I tried to add two I/O functions together, but only one segment is turning red at a time. How can I make it happen, that multiple segments are turning red at the same time and stay red for a some time?

Here is my code

```
unit check;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, i2cUsb, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { private-declarationen }
  public
    { public-declarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  board, slave : Ti2cUsb;
  var1:integer;
  i: integer;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

board := Ti2cUsb.Create;
slave := Ti2cUsb.Create;
//Comport Number COM4
var1 := board.Init(4);
Sleep(1000);
board.relais_on;
Sleep(1000);
board.relais_off;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

board.start_iic(False,64,'w');
{
// 7 Segment off:
board.wr_byte_iic($FF);
//all 7 Segments:
board.wr_byte_iic($7F);
board.wr_byte_iic($BF);
board.wr_byte_iic($DF);
board.wr_byte_iic($EF);
board.wr_byte_iic($F7);
board.wr_byte_iic($FB);
board.wr_byte_iic($FD);
board.wr_byte_iic($FE);
}

// Display off
        board.wr_byte_iic($FF);
        sleep(5000);


//number 0:
      board.wr_byte_iic($7F);
      board.wr_byte_iic($BF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($DF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($F7);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FB);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FD);
      sleep(5000);

//number 1:
      board.wr_byte_iic($DF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($F7);
      sleep(5000);


//number 2:
      board.wr_byte_iic($BF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($DF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FE);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FD);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FB);
      sleep(5000);

//number 3:
      board.wr_byte_iic($BF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($DF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FE);
      board.wr_byte_iic($F7);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FB);
      sleep(5000);

//number 4:
      board.wr_byte_iic($7F);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FE);
      board.wr_byte_iic($DF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($F7);
      board.wr_byte_iic($EF);
      sleep(5000);

//number 5:
      board.wr_byte_iic($BF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($7F);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FE);
      board.wr_byte_iic($F7);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FB);
      sleep(5000);

//number 6:
      board.wr_byte_iic($EF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($BF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($7F);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FD);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FB);
      board.wr_byte_iic($F7);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FE);
      sleep(5000);

//number 7:
      board.wr_byte_iic($BF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($DF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($F7);
      sleep(5000);

//number 8:
      board.wr_byte_iic($FF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($7F);
      board.wr_byte_iic($BF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($DF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($F7);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FB);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FD);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FE);
      sleep(5000);

//number 9:
      board.wr_byte_iic($EF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FE);
      board.wr_byte_iic($7F);
      board.wr_byte_iic($BF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($DF);
      board.wr_byte_iic($F7);
      board.wr_byte_iic($FB);
      sleep(5000);

// Display off
      board.wr_byte_iic($FF);



end;

end.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I understand the chip, when your write a byte (that is 8 bits), each bit correspond to a segment, the segment is on when corresponding bit is zero. This means $FF turn all segments to OFF, $00 turn all segments to on ("8") and $D7 turn two segment ON ("1"). Try and tell me...

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But how did you know that $D7 turn on two segment ("1")?

Comment: That is in your code under the comment "// number 1": $DF is binary 11011111 and $F7 is binary 11110111, you simply misunderstood how to combine two "negative logic" numbers (0 is active). It is with the AND operator $DF and $F7 is $D7 (11010111 => the two zeros will turn two segments on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are trying to write multiple segments, each write is replacing what you have written previously.  You need to work out the number corresponding to the combination of segments you want to show, and then write that combined number, once.

There are a number of ways to do this.  I think I would do something like this:

```pascal
implementation
  const      ALL_OFF   = $ff;
  const      SEGMENT_1 = $20;      // ONE bit only set, the bit that needs to
  const      SEGMENT_2 = $08;      //     turned off for that segment

procedure SetNumberOne();
var
  ByteToWrite: Byte;
begin
  ByteToWrite := ALL_OFF Xor (SEGMENT_1 Or SEGMENT_2);
  board.wr_byte_iic(ByteToWrite);
end;
```

So you have constants marking the bits that need to be set off, you `Or` these together to get the correct combination of bits, then `Xor` with $FF to turn off the bits corresponding the segments you want to display.

Comment: In the debugger did you check that `ByteToWrite` is the value you expect (`$d7`) and that this is the value to give you what you want?